# Calculating the percentage of a GROUP_BY with a WHERE statement

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Let's say I have a table with orders with revenue and status columns. I want to group the orders by revenue group (grouped by increments of 10) and get the percentage of which have their status column set to 1 in their respective revenue group. I thought a window function was the way to go, but the where statement restricts the columns so that I end up with only the columns where status == 1.
The end result would look something like: `10 | 76%`, `20 | 50%` etc.

```sql
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN revenue between 1 and 10 then 10
  WHEN revenue between 10 and 20 then 20
  WHEN revenue between 20 and 30 then 30
  WHEN revenue between 30 and 40 then 40
  WHEN revenue between 40 and 50 then 50
  else 60 
END as revgroup,
COUNT(*) / CAST(SUM(count(*)) over (partition by CASE 
  WHEN revenue between 1 and 10 then 10
  WHEN revenue between 10 and 20 then 20
  WHEN revenue between 20 and 30 then 30
  WHEN revenue between 30 and 40 then 40
  WHEN revenue between 40 and 50 then 50
else 60 END) as float) as percentage
from "order"
where "order".status = 1
group by revgroup
```

Answer (score 0):

the clause PARTITION BY is excessive in your case, each partition was created using clause GROUP BY

```
SELECT CASE 
  WHEN revenue between 1 and 10 then 10
  WHEN revenue between 10 and 20 then 20
  WHEN revenue between 20 and 30 then 30
  WHEN revenue between 30 and 40 then 40
  WHEN revenue between 40 and 50 then 50
  else 60 
END as revgroup,
COUNT(*) * 1.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER () as percentage
from "order"
where "order".status = 1
group by revgroup
```